# Retag existing AWS resources using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, tagging, aws-serverless

Here is the thing, I have a serverless project that creates many AWS resources (Lambdas, API Gateway, etc), now I need to change the tags I used a couple of months ago, but when I try to run the serverless I see this message: " A version for this Lambda function exists ( 6 ). Modify the function to create a new version..". I have been reading and applying a couple of different workarounds but same issue.

Does any body have seen this behavior? Is there a way to retag all resources withouth delete the whole stack or doing that manually?

Thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a serverless plugin (serverless-plugin-resource-tagging). it will tag your Lambda function, Dynamo Tables, Bucket, Stream, API Gateway, and CloudFront resources. The way it works is you have to provide stacksTags having your tags inside under the Provider section of serverless.

```
provider:
 stackTags:
        STACK: "${self:service}"
        PRODUCT: "Product Name"
        COPYRIGHT: "Copyright"
```

You can also update tags value using this plugin.